# Why does `levels<-` behave differently depending on the order of named arguments?

Tags: r

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again" -- x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> `levels<-`(factor(c("a", "b")), c("c", "d"))
[1] c d
Levels: c d
> args(`levels<-`)
function (x, value) 
NULL
> `levels<-`(x = factor(c("a", "b")), value = c("c", "d"))
[1] c d
Levels: c d
```

So far so good, and yet:

```
> `levels<-`(value = c("c", "d"), x = factor(c("a", "b")))
[1] "c" "d"
attr(,"levels")
[1] a b
Levels: a b
```

I got a different result from a call that should be equivalent. What's going on?

Comment: I want to post a full answer but the documentation isn't entirely clear to me.  I believe it's because levels<- is implemented via Primitive and requires positional matching.  Remove the named arguments from your last example and you get the same answer which provides some credibility to my assumption.  The documentation calls out some examples where positional matching is required but I didn't see anything that would imply this is one of those cases - otherwise I would have provided an answer.  https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#g_t_002eInternal-vs-_002ePrimitive

Comment: Great question btw.

Comment: From `?levels`: "The replacement function is primitive". From [R manual on Argument matching](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching): "[Primitive functions] typically ignore tags and do positional matching".

Comment: @Henrik good catch. I was just focused on the section of the manual I linked to but I think your section closes the loop on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`levels<-` is implemented via Primitive and requires positional matching. Remove the named arguments from your last example and you get the same answer.

If you examine `?levels<-` you'll see:  "The replacement function is primitive". The R manual on Argument matching (found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching)) says that primitive functions: "typically ignore tags and do positional matching"